# Is Adam a messenger of Allah? Was he given any scrolls?

Tags: sunnah, prophets, messengers

A messenger is one who gets Sunnah for himself and his followers. Since adam also had his sunnah and sunnah of any prophet is revelation from Allah is Adam to be considered as first messenger of Islam.

I'm assuming other prophets like lut / yusuf / yaqub didn't get their own sunnah because they followed sunnah of Abraham.

Answer (score 2):

This definition of messenger is debatable and has issues with it.

To answer your question though, we know for a fact that Adam (AS) was not a messenger without resorting to any theorized definitions. It comes in a hadith regarding the Day of Judgement:

> Allah will gather the believers on the Day of Resurrection in the same way (as they are gathered in this life), and they will say, 'Let us ask someone to intercede for us with our Lord that He may relieve us from this place of ours.'
>
> Then they will go to Adam and say, 'O Adam! Don't you see the people (people's condition)? Allah created you with His Own Hands and ordered His angels to prostrate before you, and taught you the names of all the things. Please intercede for us with our Lord so that He may relieve us from this place of ours.'
>
> Adam will say, 'I am not fit for this undertaking' and mention to them the mistakes he had committed, and add, 'But you'd better go to Noah as he was the first messenger sent by Allah to the people of the Earth.'
>
> They will go to Noah who will reply, 'I am not fit for this undertaking,' [...] (Very famous hadith recorded in many books; this is a version from [Sahih Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:7410))

In this hadith, Adam (AS) himself calls Nuh (AS) the first messenger for mankind. So, it is clear Adam (AS) was not a messenger as he came before Nuh (AS).

Comment: First messenger to kuffar, first messenger to muslims is different I think. How did adam come to know about funeral rites, prayer? He was given revelation

Comment: @Abdurrehman The Prophet says "first messenger sent by Allah to the people of the Earth"

Comment: The issue is in your definition of messenger. You should change your definition to incorporate the fact that Adam (AS) was not a messenger.

Comment: Then what is definition of messenger, Ibrahim was not sent to town of homosexuals, prophet lut was sent to them, even though lut is contemporary of ibrahim

Comment: @Abdurrehman Idk the definition, but any definition one makes should conform to the evidence and clear fact that Nuh (AS) was the first messenger. You can see this video for a long discussion of the definition: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXPc6La75Ok

Comment: Hadith from aisha says Prophet didn't see Allah but ibn Abbas said Prophet saw Allah twice with his heart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122585/discussion-between-abdur-rehman-and-the-z).

Comment: A messenger is somebody who is sent by an authority to bring a message. In our context, he is sent by God to the humans. Also from this definition it makes sense that Adam is not a messenger because there was no humanity more than two.